# How extract .msi file's icon with python27

Tags: python-2.7, icons, windows-installer

I now need to use Python27 to extract the icon for the MSI file,I've tried MSilib, but it seems to only support creation and is not very friendly for reading messages.Does anyone have experience using py27 to extract MSI information? Help me

Comment: This is finally done with Ctypes: https://github.com/Wangwangwoc/MSIFile

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite the Ctypes lib.